# how to change mysql data directory in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to change the data directory of mysql. i am using 12.04 ubuntu.but i have geting error when mysql start. error is "start: Job failed to start".

I have try following things

Stop the mysql server:

```
stop mysql
```

Create the new directory:

```
mkdir /array2/mysql
```

Copy over ONLY the database folders:

```
cp -R /var/lib/mysql /array2/mysql
cp -R /var/lib/mysql/users /array2/mysql
```

Backup the `my.cnf` file:

```
cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /root/my.cnf.backup
```

Edit the `my.cnf` file:

```
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Change all mentions of the old datadir and socket to your new location

Mine became:

```
datadir=/array2/mysql
```

```
socket=/array2/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Update the directory permissions:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /array2/mysql
```

Rename the old directory:

```
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql-old
```

Create a symlink, just in case:

```
ln -s /array2/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Let AppArmor know about the new datadir:

```
echo "alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /your/new/datadir/," >> /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias
```

Reload the apparmor profiles

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload
```

Then start mysql:

```
start mysql
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at mysql error log to see why is failing to start?

Comment: @EstebanGarcia not any error found error.log file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking on your changes and it is not necesary to do symlinks, socket changes and/or remove old directory. Please follow this steps.

```
service mysql stop
cp -R /var/lib/mysql /array2/mysql
chown -R mysql.mysql /array2/mysql
```

Now take a backup /etc/my.cnf and then edit data dir variable

```
datadir                                 = /array2/mysql
```

Edit apparmor rules, usually in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld by adding the following lines inside /usr/sbin/mysqld group:

```
/array2/mysql/ r,
/array2/mysql/** rwk,
```

Reload app armor and start mysql service

```
service apparmor restart
service mysql start
```

Regards,